# Julia: Passing data between coroutines (tasks)

Tags: task, coroutine, julia

I have tried to get two tasks (coroutines) to cooperate, but to no avail.  Below is what I have.  I never see the printlns from either source or sink functions, and the wait() call appears to hang forever.  I have also tried making the p (source) task a global variable, instead of passing it to sink() as an argument, but that does not seem to work either (even when I declare it inside sinke() as a global.

This is the kind of thing that I discovered I can do very easily with channels and goroutines in Go.

I have also experimented with calling yieldto() inside the source() and sink() functions, but I still seem to end in deadlock.

Anyone with an example of multiple tasks sharing data in any way?  Ideally, I would have a pipeline, or long chain of tasks.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
println("Hello")

function source()
  println("source start")
  produce("start")
  produce("stop")
end

function sink(p::Task)
  println("sink start")
  println(consume(p))
  println(consume(p))
end


a = Task( source )
b = Task( () -> sink(a)   )

wait(b)
wait(a)

println("Goodbye")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Julia a creating a task does not automatically schedule that task. The wait function doesn't schedule either so you end up with a deadlock. This is a big difference from Go where the go statement takes care of all the scheduling for you. In julia you have to do a little more work. Specifically use the @sync and @async macros to make
it easier.

```
@sync begin # @sync will wait for all the contained tasks to terminate.
   a = @async source() # @async will create and schedule a task for you automatically
   @async sink(a)
 end
```

You'll notice though that this doesn't terminate either. All of the prints happen but the task does not terminate. The cause is @sync waiting for task a to finish but task a has not been scheduled. Add a final consume or schedule to your sink function to force task a to get scheduled one final time so it can terminate. Or better yet use a for loop on the task so you always exhaust it.

```
println("Hello")

function source()
  println("source start")
  produce("start")
  produce("stop")
  println("source end")
end

function sink(p::Task)
  println("sink start")
  for s in p
    println(s)
  end
  println("sink end")
end

@sync begin
   a = @async source()
   @async sink(a)
 end

println("Goodbye")
```

Julia's tasks are cooperatively scheduled which basically means you have to ensure each task gets scheduled by yourself. The runtime isn't going to do it for you. Luckily the @sync and @async macros do most of this for you.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for the clear answer.  I can see that julia gives much more fine-grained control over coroutines.  I appreciate your help.